# Stripe not listing new customer in dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for my ecommerce website and I have no errors with my code, but for some reason ***new customers are not being registered in my Stripe dashboard.***

At one point it was working, but not anymore. I followed the tutorial on the Stripe website.

Here is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_Zr7oAROGNha5GcEdthCemM0a');

 function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

  var $form = $('#signupform');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
   // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};

 jQuery(function($) {
  $('#signupform').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you seeing in your Stripe logs?

https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs?method=not_get

Successful calls to /v1/tokens only, or /v1/tokens and /v1/customers too?

Usually this occurs when you are creating tokens, but not also a customer or charges in your backend. Charging a customer with Stripe is always going to be a two-step process.

Step 1: You collect a customer's credit card information with Checkout or Stripe.js form, pass it to Stripe, Stripe gives you back a token.

Step 2: You take this token and pass it to your backend, then tell Stripe to make a charge with it, or save it to a customer to be charged later. You need a script on your server to handle this and grab the token from the POST parameters. There's a code sample here, https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

It sounds like this second step isn't happening for you --- if you already have a backend script there is likely some error causing it to fail before the information reaches Stripe. I'd recommend reviewing your server and error logs to find some more detail on what exactly that might be.